# JSON file updated in chrome not working in firefox

Tags: php, json, jquery, firefox

Hi I am trying to edit and save some data in my existing JSON file, here is the code -

```
var newData = { mailTo: 'abc@123.com'};

$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'jsonHandler.php',
data: newData,
}).done(function( formData ) {
formData = eval('(' + formData + ')');
$('#mail').val( formData.load[0].mailTo );
});
```

This works in chrome and IE but the JSON is not getting updated when I run it using firefox.

Here is the request header generate in Firefox (got using firebug)

```
Request Headers
Accept  */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Content-Length  12
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Host    localhost
Referer http://localhost/gandu/
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

The jsonHandler.php code

```
<?php
require_once('JSON.php');

    $json = new Services_JSON();

    $json_data = json_decode(file_get_contents('formData.json'), true);

    if (isset( $_POST['formId'])) {
        $json_data['load'][0]['formId'] = $_POST['formId'];
    } else {
        echo 'No text found';
    }

    if (isset( $_POST['mailTo'])) {
        $json_data['load'][0]['mailTo'] = $_POST['mailTo'];
    } else {
        echo 'No text found';
    }

    $output = ($json->encode($json_data));

    file_put_contents('formData.json', $output);

    print ($output);

    ?>
```

Is there something I am doing wrong.

Error in firebug -

```
    SyntaxError: missing ) in parenthetical

a()jquery.min.js (line 2)
    e = Object { url="jsonHandler.php", isLocal=false, global=true, more...}
    n = Object { readyState=4, 

    responseText="No text found{"load":[{..."qq","fmessage":"qq"}]}", status=200, more...}
        r = Object { text="No text found{"load":[{..."qq","fmessage":"qq"}]}"}
        a()jquery.min.js (line 2)
        e = 200
        n = "OK"
        s = Object { text="No text found{"load":[{..."qq","fmessage":"qq"}]}"}
        a = "Date: Sat, 01 Jun 2013 ...ntent-Type: text/html\r\n"
        a()jquery.min.js (line 2)
        e = readystatechange
        i = undefined
        [Break On This Error]   

        (No text found{"load":[{"formId":"form2","mailTo":"def@123.com"}]
```

Shows an alert box saying error.

Comment: Don't use `eval()` to decode JSON. Specify `dataType: 'json'` in the `$.ajax()` options, and jQuery will automatically parse it when setting `formData`. Or use `$.parseJSON()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP script requires both `formId` and `mailTo` parameters, but you're only sending `mailTo`. When it doesn't see `formId`, it echoes `No text found`. This makes the result invalid JSON. You can see that in the error message: the returned string begins with:

```
No text found{"load":[{"formId":"form2","mailTo":"def@123.com"}]
```

so you're trying to do:

```
eval('(No text found{"load":[{"formId":"form2","mailTo":"def@123.com"}]...)');
```

but that string is not valid Javascript, so the eval gets an error.

You either have to change the PHP so it reports errors in a different way, or change the Javascript so it removes this from the returned string before decoding it.

You also shouldn't use `eval()` to parse JSON. Use:

```
formData = $.parseJSON(formData);
```

after removing the "No text found" prefix.

I'm also a little suspicious of `$json->encode($json_data)`. Why are you using this instead of the built-in `json_encode($json_data)`?

Comment: I have removed the else part from php script but still does not work in firefox, works in chrome though

Comment: added formData = $.parseJSON(formData); but still does not works in firefox json is not edited.

Comment: after the $.ajax I am using location.reload(), If I remove location.reload() the JSON is updated but with location.reload() it does not.

Comment: location.reload() reloads the original page, anything you add dynamically is lost.

Comment: I added the location.reload() in success part of $.ajax and it works fine now. I will test it and let you know if I face any problem

Thanks a ton mate!!!

Comment: one more question, how can I reload a particular div instead of the whole page?

Comment: `$("#somediv").load("url")` will make an AJAX call to the url and load the DIV with the returned HTML.

Comment: and if it i the same page i wanna reload?

Comment: I'm not sure, but you could try `$("somediv").load("#somediv")`. The empty URL before the hash should mean to load the current page, then jQuery will filter down to `#somediv` in the returned HTML.

Answer (score 0):

try this it will give u a better log of the error

```
var newData = { mailTo: 'abc@123.com'};
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'jsonHandler.php',
data: newData,
success: function( formData ) {
 formData = eval('(' + formData + ')');
 $('#mail').val( formData.load[0].mailTo );
 },
 error:function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown ){
   alert(textStatus + "               " +errorThrown );
 }
});
```

or on your case override .fail() for extra data

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. the error i got in firebug console is addred to the question please look

Comment: you must not use echo "No text found", at the end you are waiting for json response but the text appear will make the json in a bad format so if you need just a thing add an error var to your json to carry the error message not printing it

like this  $json_data['error'] = " item not found"